# Android : Unable to display multiple lines of text in Notification

Tags: android, notifications, notificationmanager

I am trying to display multiple lines of Text using `BigTextStyle` in Notification but unable to do so. I am using the code below.

```
public void sendNotification(View view) {
    String msgText = "Jeally Bean Notification example!! "
            + "where you will see three different kind of notification. "
            + "you can even put the very long string here.";

    NotificationManager notificationManager = getNotificationManager();
    PendingIntent pi = getPendingIntent();
    android.app.Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(
            this);
    builder.setContentTitle("Big text Notofication")
            .setContentText("Big text Notification")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "show activity", pi);
    Notification notification = new Notification.BigTextStyle(builder)
            .bigText(msgText).build();

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}

public NotificationManager getNotificationManager() {
    return (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}

public PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
            MainActivity.class), 0);
}
```

I can't even see 'msgText' in the notification. Any idea why?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved!

Code was fine, its just that there was not enough space for big notification. When I disconnected data cable, it got displayed in desired manner. :-)

Thanks to all who tried to help.

Comment: Is there any way I can show notification in full expanded mode by default instead of pinch-expand. Thanks

Comment: your code doesn't work for me. Have you changed anything in this? It just displays text in one line removing trailing text.

Comment: @AnandPrakash , as describe in answer, simply disconect the cable.

Answer (score 4):

Just set notification style to BigText

```
   NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigStyle =
   new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
   bigStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
   bigStyle.bigText(messageBody);
   builder.setStyle(bigStyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set content intent value as well.

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
builder.setContentTitle("Big text Notification")
        .setContentText("Big text Notification")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setAutoCancel(true)

        .setContentIntent(pi) // <- this new line

        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "show activity", pi);
```

Answer (score -5):

`.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)` - this line solved my problem. The multiline conserve size.

Comment: priority has nothing to do with that 

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#priority

"Relative priority for this notification. Priority is an indication of how much of the user's valuable attention should be consumed by this notification. Low-priority notifications may be hidden from the user in certain situations, while the user might be interrupted for a higher-priority notification. The system will make a determination about how to interpret this priority when presenting the notification."

Comment: you should never use priority just to make some bugfix. Priority is for priority. read the docs