# Stacking all device notification into one single notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

Hey I was wondering if it is possible to intercept and stack all device notification into one single notification? If it is how can I do that?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html see here It will help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android : Unable to display multiple lines of text in Notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449419/android-unable-to-display-multiple-lines-of-text-in-notification)

Comment: oh and how can I intercept all the other notification?

Comment: What intents are you trying to intercept? You will need a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive those intents and then send it to some other class to determine what to do with them.

Comment: All notifications which come to the device!